# iphone: NSMutableURLRequest returns strange characters for MS Word style apostrophe

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, nsmutableurlrequest

We are pulling content off our website using XML/NSMutableURLRequest and sometimes it pulls through the "curly" style apostrophe and quotes, ’ rather than '.  NSMutableURLRequest seems to hate these and turns them into the strange \U00e2\U0080\U0099 string.

Is there something that I can to do prevent this?  I am using the GET method, so should I be somehow telling it to use UTF-8?  Or, am I missing something?

```
UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url];
    NSURL *serviceUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
    NSMutableURLRequest *serviceRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:serviceUrl];
    [serviceRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    NSURLResponse *serviceResponse;
    NSError *serviceError;

    app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    return [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:serviceRequest returningResponse:&serviceResponse error:&serviceError];
```

Comment: Could you post the code related to the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSURLConnection` returns an `NSData` response. You can take that `NSData` response and turn it into a string. Then take this string, turn it back into a `NSData` object, properly UTF-8 encoding it along the way, and feed it to `NSXMLParser`.

Example: (Assuming `response` is the `NSData` response from your request)

```
// long variable names for descriptive purposes
NSString* xmlDataAsAString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:response] autorelease];
NSData* toFeedToXMLParser = [xmDataAsAString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSXMLParser* parser = [[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:toFeedToXMLParser] autorelease];
// now utilize parser...
```

Comment: Actually, I realized I was already setting an encoding, but it was NSASCIIStringEncoding, changed it to NSUTF8StringEncoding and now it works!

Comment: Awesome! Glad you figured it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest replacing those characters using `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:` to replace the unwanted strings.

```
NSString *currentTitle = @"Some string with a bunch of stuff in it.";

//Create a new range for each character.
NSRange rangeOfDash = [currentTitle rangeOfString:@"character to replace"];
NSString *location = (rangeOfDash.location != NSNotFound) ? [currentTitle substringToIndex:rangeOfDash.location] : nil;

if(location){
    currentTitle = [[currentTitle stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:location withString:@""] mutableCopy];
}
```

I've done this in the past to handle the same problem you describe.

Comment: Yeah, but this is only to fix the problem, not prevent it.  There there a way to prevent this in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: